# Join in solr to get data from two cores

Tags: join, solr, lucene

I have two solr cores. One containing products information and second has customers points. I am looking at solr join to query on first product core & boost the results based on customer points in second core. I am not able to frame solr query for this.

Moreover, solr is not allowing to get data from both the core.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot query two cores in a single request. You need to consolidate at the client, or move data into a single core.